# NuxtJS - How to call store action from any page

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have global actions, what I need to call in all pages. How can I call that action with ssr, for all pages?

I'm trying to create a plugin, and in the plugin call fetch, or asyncData(), but that does not work.

```
Vue.mixin({
  data() {
    return {
      ddt: "ddt"
    }
  },
    fetch() {
      console.log('I am fetch') // eslint-disable-line no-console
    }
});
```

I'm trying to create mixin and call fetch, but that's not working too. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at this and confirm your merging is correct for the mixin - https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/2493

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store global actions

```js
export const actions = {
 async nuxtServerInit({ dispatch }) {
    
 }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).